# My Bacula Transfer rate it's extremely low. How can i configure the director to improve this?

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

I'm creating a cloudbased solution with bacula to have backups of all our servers. We have lot's of server on premise and some others on clouds like AWS and OPENCLOUD. 
i'm seeing very low transfer rates for the backups made (i'm talking about 400kbps/s) and for small FS about 5/6GB each... this worries me because we are testing with this clients, making backups full which last 2 hour to finish, and we will be adding some really big clients later (about 500GB/1TB each) to make full backups of them

This is the message printed after the backup of this clients :

```
09-Nov 03:43 bacula-dir JobId 37: Start Backup JobId 37, Job=Backup- 
mailserverp.2018-11-08_22.15.00_13
09-Nov 06:08 bacula-sd JobId 37: Elapsed time=02:24:57, Transfer rate=580  
Bytes/second
Scheduled time:         08-Nov-2018 22:15:00
Start time:             09-Nov-2018 03:43:51
End time:               09-Nov-2018 06:08:52
Elapsed time:           2 hours 25 mins 1 sec
FD Bytes Written:       5,039,356 (5.039 MB)
SD Bytes Written:       5,048,922 (5.048 MB)



09-Nov 01:09 bacula-dir JobId 36: Start Backup JobId 36, Job=Backup- 
nagios.2018-11-08_22.15.00_12
09-Nov 03:43 bacula-sd JobId 36: Elapsed time=02:34:39, Transfer rate=386.9 K 
Bytes/second
Elapsed time:           2 hours 34 mins 47 secs
FD Bytes Written:       3,590,358,216 (3.590 GB)
SD Bytes Written:       3,590,441,488 (3.590 GB)


09-Nov 00:38 bacula-dir JobId 35: Start Backup JobId 35, Job=Backup- 
bapuppet01.2018-11-08_21.25.00_11
09-Nov 00:38 bacula-sd JobId 34: Elapsed time=02:11:17, Transfer rate=35.68 K Bytes/second
Scheduled time:         08-Nov-2018 21:05:00
Start time:             08-Nov-2018 22:27:30
End time:               09-Nov-2018 00:38:52
Elapsed time:           2 hours 11 mins 22 secs
```

This message shows three servers, being two on premise and one on the OpenCloud Cloudbased hosting. Given the structure, we assume the onpremise client will be the slowest to backup of all. but after we test the connection using  **iperf** command, we see the following :

```
FROM SERVER TO CLIENT

[root@otc-bacula ~]# iperf -c 172.xx.xx.xxx -p 9102 -i 2 -t 60
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 172.xx.xx.xxx, TCP port 9102
TCP window size: 45.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.xx.xx.xxx port 33902 connected with 172.xx.xx.xxx port 9102
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 2.0 sec  95.9 MBytes   402 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 4.0 sec   180 MBytes   754 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 6.0 sec   132 MBytes   554 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 8.0 sec  70.6 MBytes   296 Mbits/sec


FROM CLIENT TO SERVER ################################


[root@v-nagios ~]# iperf -c 172.xx.xxx.xxx -p 9102 -i 2 -t 60
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 172.xx.xxx.xxx, TCP port 9102
TCP window size: 16.0 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.xx.xxx.xxx port 41538 connected with 172.xxx.xxx.xxx port 9102
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 2.0 sec  3.75 MBytes  15.7 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 4.0 sec  4.00 MBytes  16.8 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 6.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  10.5 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 8.0 sec  4.38 MBytes  18.4 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0-10.0 sec  3.50 MBytes  14.7 Mbits/sec
[  3] 10.0-12.0 sec  2.12 MBytes  8.91 Mbits/sec
```

i have already tried despooling options, but i'm not seeing any improvement. Does anyone knows a way or a script to test performance of bacula and how to improve it ?  i can try to reduce the FileSets the more possible just  to backup what we really need, but still be a lot of files / gygas.

This is the Bacula-Dir.conf if it helps :

```
Director {                            # define myself
  Name = bacula-dir
  DIRport = 9101                # where we listen for UA connections
  DirAddress = 172.19.120.106
  QueryFile = "/etc/bacula/query.sql"
  WorkingDirectory = "/var/spool/bacula"
  PidDirectory = "/var/run"
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 10
  Password = "123456"         # Console password
  Messages = Daemon
  Heartbeat Interval = 1
}


Storage {
  Name = File
# Do not use "localhost" here
  Address = 172.19.120.106                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
  SDPort = 9103
  Password = "123456"
  Device = FileStorage
  Media Type = File
}

Pool {
  Name = File
  Pool Type = Backup
  Label Format = OpenCloud-
  Recycle = yes                       # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 365 days         # one year
  Maximum Volume Bytes = 100G          # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
  Maximum Volumes = 350               # Limit number of Volumes in Pool
}
```

I think this info is of use, but if any case you need more info of some service or need me to do something, i'll gladly provide the data needed... i'm really in need to increase the transfer rate of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've realized i was using MySql as a DB backend, and was having troubles with the bulks of insert data. So i made a fresh install again, but this time using Postgresql as database, and reached almost 40 mb/s as transfer rate . great improve

I'll mark my own answer as the correct

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pieces of advice on Bacula tuning:

1. MySQL is also supported in Bacula, but almost always requires tuning as you discovered. The automatic mysql tuning script can be very helpful here.
   https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
2. PostgreSQL does seem to scale much better especially for Bacula, but still requires tuning. Pedro wrote a nice guide here: http://www.pedroliveira.pt/index.php/bacula-performance-tunnig-with-postgresql/

And, if you haven't already, it would also be a good idea to join the Bacula-users mailing list where you can search the archives and get help with other Bacula questions. https://www.bacula.org/support/email-lists/

Finally, Bacula Systems can provide tuning guidance if you have a subscription.

Note: I work for Bacula Systems as CDMO.

Comment: Just as a general guidance, if you are affiliated with a product you link to, such as being the CDMO at Bacula Systems like you list in your profile, it's generally required that you disclose your affiliation *directly in your answer*. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) for further information about how to format your posts.